# django: how can i get the last id or row_id of a table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing a website, i need to make a numbering system, i need to add `the latest row_id/id + 1` to a charfield, alll work is nearly done but this.
any idea how to get the number? its like getting the row id of the object before adding it to the table.

```
letter_numbering = cjy + latest_row_id +1

~~~

class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    jalali_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=current_full_j_date)
->  letter_number = models.CharField(max_length=7, default=letter_numbering)
    from_to = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    file = forms.FileField()
    letter_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=letter_direction, default='incoming')
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#autofield)? Why not just use your primary key?

Comment: Probably **`@property`** might suite for you rather than a DB field

Comment: Apart from that, you are using **`forms.FileField()`** in models, you shouldn't be

Comment: not exactly autofill, i want to have ```some number e.g. year``` +  ```incrementing number```
for example: 20200001, 2020002, 2020003 and so on. any ideas, consider i am newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question what I get is you want the id of latest record that you inserted
It can be obtained using:-

```
   latest_id = Entry.objects.latest('id').id
```

In your model, there is no primary key so Django will create a default primary key i.e id which will be incremented automatically every time you create a record.
So you can use it as the latest row_id.
Based on the autokey id you can get the last created id as

```
   last_id = Entry.objects.last().id
```

Either of these will give solution to your question.

Comment: thanks for the assisst, where shall i use your code? when i use above th class it i get error: ```name 'Entry' is not defined```

Comment: You should write views.py.
In that import your model's file.
Sample code to check, you can use according to your need

from models import *
   def get_id():
      latest_id = Entry.objects.latest('id').id
      print(latest_id)
   get_id()

Comment: hum... i think im so new to this. could yoou help more with that? and write the codes? so that maybe i understand what exactly goes on with that.

Comment: Create a python file in same directory and named views.py and write below code.Indent it. I don't know well how to write comment in code 
from models import * 

def get_id(): 
    latest_id = Entry.objects.latest('id').id print(latest_id) 

get_id()
Maybe below link can be helpful to give basic idea about the framework
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/